# How to pass expression to a join query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I do have a LINQ join query like this:

```
public List<Cn> GetAll()
        {
            var query = context.CNs
                .Join(
                    context.Projects,
                    cn => cn.RefPrjno,
                    prj => prj.Id,
                    (cn, prj) => new { cn, prj }
                 )
                .Where(x => x.cn.Status == "B" || x.cn.Status == "C" || x.cn.Status == "E")
                .Select(x => new Cn
                {
                    Id = x.cn.Id,
                    Status = x.cn.Status,
                    Cnno = x.cn.Cnno,
                    RefPrjno = x.cn.RefPrjno,
                    PrjDescr = x.prj.Descr
                    Createdon = x.cn.Createdon,
                    Createdby = x.cn.Createdby
                }
                ).ToList();

            return query;
        }
```

The where part depends on parameters from API call, which I'd like to call from the controller like this:

this:

```
var entities = await cnRepository.GetAll(
                (a => a.Status == "B" || a.Status == "C" || a.Status == "E");
```

I mean, I'd like to pass the where part as a function.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Cn>> GetAll(Expression<Func<Cn, bool>> filter = null)
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Simple answer: it isn't possible - your `Join` returns an anonymous object `new { ... }` which would be the type of the parameter to `GetAll` but the caller can't see that type or use it. Complex answer: you could create an `Expression` tree builder method to potentially do it, or you could use a known type for the `Join` result (such as `ValueTuple` or a class you create).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Do you have an example for the Expression builder?